# Can I write an app for my android phone using VB?

Tags: android, vb.net

I have struggled using Word for this need but it is cryptic.  If I could understand how to use Excel in the phone, it might work.  However, I am beginning to see that I should design my own app and the only programming language I know well enough is Visual BASIC.

Can this work?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please re-write your question.

Comment: Try [B4A](https://www.b4x.com/b4a.html), almost same syntax as VB

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this B4A programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I believe that you will find quite a bit of trouble in making the app via VB. Luckily for you, if you can code it and have it work in VB, then it shouldn't be much more than a matter of learning syntax for another language to get done what you need to (java or javascript would be my choice).

Comment: Valid point, that is one of the many options Carol has. And being safe to assume she already has Visual Studio, she would already have everything needed except knowledge of the language.

Comment: I don't think that is a safe assumption. She talks about trying to use Excel on the phone, which makes me think she's actually writing in VBA, specifically in Excel.

Comment: Yes, I have extensive knowledge of VBA.  Maybe I am mixing too many technologies in my mind....  As I mentioned elsewhere, I think I will test my ideas writing a program in VB on my desktop then I can test it first.    I will then think about getting it over to my phone as an app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so.

If you're prepared to jump the gap to C# then Xamarin will interest you. It's bundled with modern versions of Visual Studio so there's lots of examples and support out there on it.

Have a read and see if it's for you: https://www.xamarin.com/getting-started/android

edit: slightly newer link: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/hello,android_quickstart/

Comment: Actually, I was hoping for a VB direct to App method. Although I do have some C coding experience, I doubt I will be able explore C# or C++ enough to make the conversion, it has been so many years since I used anything other than VB....  Maybe I eill create the prototype in VB then hire someone to make the app.

Comment: Now that I see it, Xamarin looks good, a lot of familiar screen in the link demo.  Thanks, I will look into it.  I just received an assignment from the University so I will have to stick with VB for now but maybe I can get some of the students to delve into it with me in a month or two.

Thanks.